# DataTables dynamic cells won't render

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm stuck with getting my datatable cells (column 'price') re-rendered based on drop-down value (currency). But as I select currency, nothing is happening with the table - all the figures just stay the same. Any ideas as of why render function fails to render?

My HTML+JavaScript is as follows:

```js
var oldCurrency = 'usd';
var newCurrency = 'usd';

var myTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    sDom: 't',
    columns:[
      {data: 'item', title: 'Item'},
      {data: 'descr', title: 'Description'},
      {data: 'cost', title: 'Cost', render: function(data, type, row){
       var exchangeRate = {usd: 1, eur: 0.87, gbp: 0.78};
        row.cost = row.cost*exchangeRate[newCurrency]/exchangeRate[oldCurrency];
        return row.cost;
      }}
    ]
  });
  
$('#currency').on('focus', function(){
 oldCurrency = this.value;
});

$('#currency').on('change', function(){
 newCurrency = this.value;
  myTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <select id="currency">
    <option value="usd">USD</option>
    <option value="eur">EUR</option>
    <option value="gbp">GBP</option>
  </select>
  <table id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>pen</td>
        <td>writing tool</td>
        <td>5.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>pencil</td>
        <td>wooden stick</td>
        <td>4.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>eraser</td>
        <td>piece of rubber</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't do all the tedious HTML on your own - even if your data is static and you don't want all the features offered by ajax-sourced table, I'd rather use javascript source - I may guess, input data format would be closer to what you get from your SQL or MongoDB, or whatever backend storage you might use.

Next, I would split your model from the view in MVC terms and manipulate source data, rather then its visual representation. Even though your price data to certain extent always stays the same, DataTables might percieve those as different number figures. And thus, you may need to clean datatable contents and populate that with new figures.

So, your code with slight tweaks would look like:

```js
var oldCurrency = 'usd';
var newCurrency = 'usd';

var tableData = [
 {
   item: 'pen',
    descr: 'writing tool',
    cost: 5.5
  },
  {
   item: 'pencil',
    descr: 'wooden stick',
    cost: 3.75
  },
  {
   item: 'eraser',
    descr: 'piece of rubber',
    cost: 1.2
  },
];

var dataTable =
 $('#mytable').DataTable({
    sDom: 't',
    data: tableData,
    columns:[
      {data: 'item', title: 'Item'},
      {data: 'descr', title: 'Description'},
      {data: 'cost', title: 'Cost', render: function(data, type, row){return row.cost.toPrecision(2)}}
    ]
  });



$('#currency').on('focus', function(){
 oldCurrency = this.value;
});

$('#currency').on('change', function(){
 newCurrency = this.value;
  let exchangeRate = {usd: 1, eur: 0.87, gbp: 0.78};
  dataTable.clear();
  $.each(tableData, function(){
   let entry = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
   entry.cost = this.cost*exchangeRate[newCurrency]/exchangeRate[oldCurrency];
    dataTable.row.add(entry);
  });
 dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <select id="currency">
    <option value="usd">USD</option>
    <option value="eur">EUR</option>
    <option value="gbp">GBP</option>
  </select>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```